# Как переименовать группу директорий по маске с удалением индекса в начале имени?

Tags: bash

Есть директории вида:

```
0-1-file_name_a
2-5-file_name_b
3-1-file_name_3
```

Надо привести их к виду:

```
file_name_a
file_name_b
file_name_3
```

Утилиту rename использовать не могу в связи с её отсутствием.

Как решить проблему из командной строки с помощью find или другими средствами?

Update:
Нашёл следующее рабочее решение for d in [0-9]*; do mv "$d" "${d/[0-9]*[0-9]-/}"; done
Если перед переименованием надо посмотреть вывод потока, добавить echo между do и mv.

Comment: что за окружение у вас применяется?

Comment: Поясните, что вы имеете ввиду под окружением.

Comment: Похоже роутер какой-то)

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, sed'ом:

```
ls | sed -rne 's!^.-.-\(file_name_.\)$!mv "&" "\1"!p'
```

После того, как проверишь, что всё правильно, можно собственно запустить, заменив последнюю `p` на `e`.

---

**Update** для не-GNU sed'а:

Вообще говоря, в POSIX-совместимом `sed`'е нет ключа `-r` и флага `e` команды `s`, первое — не страшно, нужно лишь немного больше слешей, а вот без `e` придётся добавлять оболочку в конвеер:

```
ls | sed -ne 's!^.-.-\(file_name_.\)$!mv "&" "\1"!p' | sh -
```

Comment: Попробовал. sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: : RE error: parentheses not balanced А как будет выглядеть, если не file_name_. а произвjльное имя abc_def hgi_fjk в том числе uvw_xwz_2?

Comment: @Ashavan, да, вторую скобку упустил... по поводу имени,  например `[0-9a-z_]*` вместо `file_name_.` или просто `.*` — здесь к твоим услугам вся мощь [базовых] регэкспов для составления выражений и обратных ссылок для их перетасовывания...

Comment: @Fat_Zer а в каком месте скобка пропущена? Вроде всё парно стоит и всё равно не работает.

Comment: @Ashavan, заэскейпить забыл... что-то я с редактором не дружу — третий раз одно и тоже место правлю))